# I cannot update anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am using Anaconda3 4.0.0 on windows 8.1 (both X64). I try to update via:

```
conda update --all
```

and I get the error:

```
    Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: .....Error: Could not find URL: https://github.com/pympler/pympler/win-64/
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

First do :

```
conda update conda
```

then

```
conda update anaconda
```

Comment: Sorry, no luck. For the first command you gave I get the same error. Inded, the https://github.com/pympler/pympler/win-64/ leads to 404 error. Should I change smth in the config files of anaconda?

Comment: I don't think so. If your installation is correct, this should work... Maybe you try again in a little while? (Are you sure your internet connection is okay? Are you behind a FW?)

Comment: No firewall. I am struggling with this for 3 hours, even after reinstalling anaconda with a fresh version.

Comment: Sorry to hear, and sorry I can't help you better, but I have seen nothing that says conda/anaconda changed their update commands.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your answer.